# Disabling strict mode does not take effect from the config file

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to disable the MySQL/MariaDB strict mode in the variable `sql_mode`. But it doesn´t work. My my.cnf in section `[mysqld]` got this line:

```
sql_mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

But it doesn´t take effect. If I log into the database as root use and execute the following command it works fine:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

So, how I can make this change persistent?

Comment: I think you can change it with `GRANT command`

Comment: how to do it with?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html